# Problem with creation of instances of classes inside another class

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to create a class from within a class but I'm now very confused about how can that be done. I've tried for hours and hava had no luck, and my beginner level in c++ has limited me also a bit.

I've been using this link for reference with no success :/:

[Creating instance in an another class of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289540/creating-instance-in-an-another-class-of-an-object)

This is my code:

Big class Sensor.h:

```
#ifndef SENSOR_H
#define SENSOR_H
#include "Dummy_Sensor.h"
#include "Lovato_DMG610.h"

class Sensor{
  public:
    double last10Vals [10];
    char id[2];
    Lovato_DMG610 dataSource(2);
    Sensor(unsigned char dataSize){ 
      }

    int getSensorData ()
    {
      return 0;
    }
  private:
    unsigned char dataSize;
};

#endif
```

My smaller class Lovato_DMG610.h:

```
#ifndef _KERN_LOVATO_DMG610
#define _KERN_LOVATO_DMG610

#include <Arduino.h>

//using namespace std; 
class Lovato_DMG610{
  public:
    double variable = 0;

    Lovato_DMG610(uint8_t pinToConnect)
    {
      _pinToConnect=pinToConnect;
    }


  private:
    uint8_t _pinToConnect;
};

#endif
```

I've been getting an error related to the first file:

```
Sensor.h:10: error: 'Lovato_DMG610' does not name a type
     Lovato_DMG610 dataSource(2);
```

My question for you guys would be:

1. How could i include the Lovato class in order to avoid this error?
2. How should the Lovato parameters should be set from Sensor class?
   (this question is related to an error I'm also getting "Sensor.h:10: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
    Lovato_DMG610 dataSource(2);")
3. I was using the code: using namespace std; before all class declarations and I get it is not a good practice (https://www.quora.com/What-does-using-namespace-std-mean-in-C++). Nevertheless, I would like to ask you if you could advise me whether this should be used in the scope of any of these headers.

Main program will keep an array of Sensor objects in which i want to make queries to different sensors. The only include in my `Header.h` is Sensors.h.

Thank you!

*Update:* After correcting the initialization as proposed by vll the constructor is ok (question 2 is resolved) but the same 'Lovato_DMG610' does not name a type' in Sensor.h error appears every time.

Comment: There's a stray `#endif` in Sensor.h.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/x-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c

Comment: Doesn't Lovato_DMG610 need to be public?

Comment: Dear Eckhardt, thank you i just corrected it. Dabas: In Sensor.h i'm including the declaration of Lovato before creating its instance, why would it not identify it?. Pieter21, should I include an additional public statement before function declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters should be set in the constructor:

```
Lovato_DMG610 dataSource;
Sensor(unsigned char dataSize) : dataSource(2)
{}
```

Comment: You can use `Lovato_DMG610 dataSource{2};`. I would even say it's to be prefered as a way of default initializing a member.

Comment: Thank you!! For the declaration of the Lovato_DMG610 class do you guys know what could be going on that the compiler fails to know about it?